# Is System.Xml.XPath supported in .NET core 1.0? VS 2015 doesn't think so

Tags: .net-core

I'm trying to port a library from .Net 4.x to .Net core 1.0 and one error (of many) that I'm getting in VS 2015 is that "XPath" is not part of the System.Xml namespace. (Ie: this using statement fails: using System.Xml.XPath)

Yet when I look in the spec for NetStandard.Library 1.6, it looks like it's still part of the spec:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src

What's going on?

Michael

Answer (score 3):

There is some confusion here.

- The provided link is the list of source code roughly reflecting the class library programmed as part of the .NET Core (xplat) implementation. However, this does not reflect the `netstandard` contract or the `NETStandard.Library` in a 1:1 relationship. There are platform-agnostic libraries in it 
  (for example `System.Buffers`) which are not part of the ".NET Platform Standard" and on the other hand libraries which are only useful for .NET Core (some of these: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.App/).
- The `System.Xml.XPath` namespace is implemented in `System.Xml.Xpath` library/NuGet on top of `netstandard1.3`+. Therefore, it is available as a platform agnostic assembly.
- The `netstandard` covers a set of API which are required to be implemented by a .NET Platform (like .NET Core, .NET Framework, Mono, Xamarin, and hopefully in future Unity3D). On top of them, there are countless libraries which platform agnostic (like `System.Xml.XPath` or `System.Collections.Immutable`). Confusingly, these count also as part of the ".NET Standard Library". However, the meta package `NETStandard.Library` covers in my humble opinion only the contracted part of the `netstandard` but not the agnostic libraries on top.

[image: BCL Library]

For `System.Xml.XPath` this makes somehow all sense. It is a kind of *deprecated* API which is not an element of a ".NET Platform Standard" (which is a strict requirement for .NET implementations) but still available as part of the ".NET Standard Library" available for everyone on every platform to use.

Answer (score 1):

You should add dependency to [System.Xml.XPath](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Xml.XPath/).